# Updating certain values of text in a loop

Tags: c#, console-application

I want to see numbers updated only in console app, here is how I try to achieve this:

```
int successEntryCount = 0;
int failedEntryCount = 0;

Console.WriteLine("App Started:");

foreach (var entity in entities)
{
    var res = bll.AsiErtelemeIptalPaketiGonder(entity);
    if (res.State == Framework.Entities.MessageResultState.SUCCESS)
        successEntryCount++;
    else
        failedEntryCount++;

    Console.WriteLine("success :{0}", successEntryCount);
    Console.WriteLine("fail:{0}", failedEntryCount);
}
```

Of course it duplicates the line and `Console.Clear()` is not a good option since the text would be blinking too fast. I just want to see only these numbers updated.

Comment: If you *really-really* want to create such a complex UI in a console application use Miguel de Icaza's [gui.cs](https://github.com/migueldeicaza/gui.cs).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [Console.SetCursorPosition](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.console.setcursorposition(v=vs.110).aspx) method. Let's take a look at this simple example:

```
int successEntryCount = 0,
    failedEntryCount = 10,
    l = Console.CursorLeft,
    t = Console.CursorTop;

for (int i = 0; i < 2000; i++)
{
    Thread.Sleep(100);
    Console.SetCursorPosition(l, t);

    Console.WriteLine("success :{0}", successEntryCount++);
    Console.WriteLine("fail:{0}", failedEntryCount++);
    //or
    //Console.Write("success :{0} fail:{1}", successEntryCount++ , failedEntryCount++);
}
```

It will update/print values without flickering.

There is more options (if you find them more attractive for you) to achieve same thing, for example:

```
Console.Write("\rsuccess :{0} fail:{1}", successEntryCount++, failedEntryCount++); //Carriage return
```

`\r` represents a carriage return (character 13) which means the cursor returns to the start of the line.

or

```
Console.Write("\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\bsuccess :{0} fail:{1}", successEntryCount++ , failedEntryCount++); //Using backspaces
```

`\b` is backspace character (character 8).

References: **[MSDN Escape Sequences](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h21280bw.aspx)**

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Console.SetCursorPosition` to set the cursor position. Also not to loose the existing console logs (already logged like - App Started: in your case), you can set the cursor position based on retrieved left and top position. The current left and right position can be retrieved using `Console.CursorLeft` and `Console.CursorTop` properties.

```
int successEntryCount = 0;
int failedEntryCount = 0;

Console.WriteLine("App Started:");

int left = Console.CursorLeft;
int right = Console.CursorTop;

foreach (var entity in entities)
{
    var res = bll.AsiErtelemeIptalPaketiGonder(entity);
    if (res.State == Framework.Entities.MessageResultState.SUCCESS)
        successEntryCount++;
    else
        failedEntryCount++;

    Console.SetCursorPosition(left, right);
    Console.WriteLine("success :{0}", successEntryCount);
    Console.WriteLine("fail:{0}", failedEntryCount);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of

```
Console.WriteLine("success :{0}", successEntryCount);
Console.WriteLine("fail:{0}", failedEntryCount);
```

you might try something like

```
Console.Write("success :{0} fail:{1}            \r", successEntryCount, failedEntryCount);
```